# ADFS Relying Party With Third Party Claims Provider and Enforce MFA With DUO

Tags: adfs

I have a requirement where User Tries to access the App1, which is integrated with ADFS over SAML, now user gets redirected to ADFS and for the App1 (RP) Claims Provider is Another IdP.
Now i have requirement when user comes back to ADFS after authentication from IdP, want to force the user to perform the MFA with Duo, configured as MFA Authentication Adapter.

It works fine when RP is configured to user Active Directory only for Authentication.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.